# nginx не заходит в нужный location

Tags: nginx

Есть несколько директив `location`, с которыми у меня возникли проблемы. Есть главный location, в теле которого происходит редирект на `location @prerender { }`, но после объявления этого локейшена у меня идут ещё два:

```
location ~ ^\/tickets\/([a-z_-]+)\/([a-z_-]+)\/$ {
    if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
        return 410;
    }

    index /tickets/generator.php;
}

location ~ ^\/airlines\/([a-z_-]+)\/$ {
    index /airlines/generator.php;
}
```

Вот в них, почему-то, и происходит последний вход вместо того, чтобы войти в локейшн pre-render. Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы сначала происходил вход в @prerender, а затем уже в остальные location? У меня в теле пререндера есть только проверка на user-agent ботов. Вот не хотелось бы использовать if и регулярное выражение в каждом из блоков. If Is Evil всё-таки.

Полный код серверного блока:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name www.flaut.ru;

    root /var/www/production/flaut;
    index index.php index.html;

    if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php$") {
        return 301 $1;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location / {
        if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
            return 410;
        }

        try_files $uri @prerender;
    }

    location @prerender {
        proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token dSNi2kdNQINXTYUCKiUd;

        set $prerender 0;

        if ($http_user_agent ~* "http:\/\/yandex.com\/bots|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
            set $prerender 1;
        }

        if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
          set $prerender 0;
        }

        if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
            set $prerender 0;
        }

        resolver 8.8.8.8;

        if ($prerender = 1) {
            set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
            rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
            proxy_pass http://$prerender;
        }
    }

    location ~* ^.+.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|json|svg|woff2)$ {
        access_log        off;
        expires           7d;
    }

    location ~* ^.+.(html|php)$ {
        expires           epoch;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root /var/www/production/flaut/error-pages/404;
        internal;
    }

    error_page 403 /403.html;
    location = /403.html {
        root /var/www/production/flaut/error-pages/403;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ ^\/tickets\/([a-z_-]+)\/([a-z_-]+)$ {
        rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
    }

    location ~ ^\/tickets\/([a-z_-]+)\/([a-z_-]+)\/$ {
        if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
            return 410;
        }

        index /tickets/generator.php;
    }

    location ~ ^\/airlines\/([a-z_-]+)\/$ {
        index /airlines/generator.php;
    }

    # SSL-сертификат
    include snippets/ssl-flaut/ssl-flaut.ru.conf;
}
```

Comment: Полный код серверного блока в студию

Comment: @AlexeyTen добавил. Он большой, поэтому сюда его вставлять не стал, ради удобочитаемости.

Comment: Весёлый nginx чурается нудных locations.

Comment: [перечитайте ещё раз](https://www.nginx.ru/ru/docs/http/request_processing.html), чтобы уяснить, что программа *nginx* выбирает **один**, наиболее подходящий блок `location`, и именно его интерпретирует. а чтобы включить один и тот же код в несколько блоков, имеет смысл поместить его в файл и подключать директивой `include`.